# bind between various keys in the appsettings.json file

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am following this sample :

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-OIDC/MyOrg

The app-settings.json file is as follows :

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "[Enter 'common', or 'organizations' or the Tenant Id (Obtained from the Azure portal. Select 'Endpoints' from the 'App registrations' blade and use the GUID in any of the URLs), e.g. da41245a5-11b3-996c-00a8-4d99re19f292]",
    "ClientId": "[Enter the Client Id (Application ID obtained from the Azure portal), e.g. ba74781c2-53c2-442a-97c2-3d60re42f403]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

If proper values are put in AzureAd, it works fine, How ever if I want to switch between different app-registrations, How would I do that?

for instance I have the following

```
{
  "AzureAdTest": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "[Enter 'common', or 'organizations' or the Tenant Id (Obtained from the Azure portal. Select 'Endpoints' from the 'App registrations' blade and use the GUID in any of the URLs), e.g. da41245a5-11b3-996c-00a8-4d99re19f292]",
    "ClientId": "[Enter the Client Id (Application ID obtained from the Azure portal), e.g. ba74781c2-53c2-442a-97c2-3d60re42f403]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },

"AzureAdProduction": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "[Enter 'common', or 'organizations' or the Tenant Id (Obtained from the Azure portal. Select 'Endpoints' from the 'App registrations' blade and use the GUID in any of the URLs), e.g. da41245a5-11b3-996c-00a8-4d99re19f292]",
    "ClientId": "[Enter the Client Id (Application ID obtained from the Azure portal), e.g. ba74781c2-53c2-442a-97c2-3d60re42f403]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

How do I switch back to test, dev and environment?

This is the startup.cs and doesnot have any reference to it.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace blazorserver_singleOrg
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
            // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
            // 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'
            // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token.
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            // Add authentication with Microsoft identity platform.
             services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);


            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To switch between different environments:

Create two settings.json file

One for testing and one for development:

***Appsettings.Development.json***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "your-tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "your-app-id-here",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "TenantId": "your-tenant-id-here"
  }
}
```

[image]

Similarly ***Appsettings.Test.json***

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "your-tenant-domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "your-app-id-here",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "TenantId": "your-tenant-id-here"
  }
}
```

In the **Startup.cs** file of your app, add the following code to read the configuration settings based on the current environment:

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add configuration
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            // Configure Azure AD authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options));
 ...

}
```

[image]
Set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development or Test to switch between the environments.
[image]

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: **"add the following code to read the configuration settings based on the current environment"**. I believe this is not needed because ASP.NET Core applications read appsettings based on the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-application-configuration-sources).